# Excel VBA: identify and export a group of values for modification based on single item in said group

Tags: vba, excel

I have a rather complex task today and could use some guidance.

**Let me set the scene:** 
I have a excel workbook with two sheets.

The main worksheet contains a lot of data with unique IDs and some attributes.
Those IDs are grouped into unevenly sized groups by a Group variable.
Visually it looks something like this:

```
ID  -  Group  -  Attribute1  -  Attribute2  -  Attribute3  -  ...
11  -   1001  -           0  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
12  -   1001  -           1  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
11  -   1001  -           1  -           0  -     integer  -  ...
44  -   1002  -           0  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
15  -   1002  -           1  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
21  -   1002  -           0  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
97  -   1002  -           1  -           0  -     integer  -  ...
32  -   1002  -           1  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
33  -   1003  -           0  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
```

The second sheet should become an input mask to modify the groups in the main sheet. The idea is that you have one unique ID which you enter, and are then able to manipulate the attributes of the whole group said ID belongs to.
It could look something like this:

```
Enter ID here:  ##    
**Search!**<-Button

------------------
This ID belongs to Group ####!

All entries for group ####:
ID  -  Attribute1  -  Attribute2  -  Attribute3  -  ...
##  -           0  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
##  -           0  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
##  -           0  -           1  -     integer  -  ...
##  -           0  -           1  -     integer  -  ...

**Update all Changes!** <- Button
```

After making the appropriate changes the mask should update those new values in the main sheet at the corresponding places.

**What I have so far:**

I have a code which does this whole procedure for one ID at a time.
It searches for the given ID in the main sheet and fills the mask with the corresponding values, which can be changed in the mask and those changes can at the end be saved back to the main sheet.

I did this with 
`Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, after:=searchRange.Cells(searchRange.Cells.Count))` and the used `foundCell.Offset(0, -8).Value` to fill the mask with relevant attributes. And vice versa to save the changes back.

**What I am looking for:**
I am searching for a command / commands that allow me to fill the mask with the entire group of IDs at once, and save this entire group back to where it came from.
As far as I am aware this is not feasibly doable with the Offset command.
However, I have no Idea which approach could replace it.

I look forward to reading and experimenting with all you nice folk's ideas.

Thank you so very much ;)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, maybe you could find the ID and return the Group number. Then use that to filter the Group column and make changes directly on the Main sheet.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind as a backup solution ;D.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to use an AutoFilter `Range.AutoFilter(Field, Criteria1, Operator, Criteria2, VisibleDropDown)` to filter for the groupID (found with `.Find` via the ID) and then copy over the filtered range to your input mask `SheetX.AutoFilter.Range.Copy`.

You can copy back the inputs with another button (etc. "Save Changes") or use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` in combination with `If Not Application.Intersect(YourRange, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then`  which needs way more resources since it copies every time a cell in your range has changed.

Adding new lines should also be possible with that if you calculate your range every time you press one of the buttons.

Comment: This sounds very intriguing! Thank you very much! I'm off experimenting a bit. Would you mind if I might shoot you a message if I have a question regarding this approach?

Comment: Sure, I hope I can answer them =)